# Replacing bluebird with node.js native promises breaks Promise.reject

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

The following code works perfectly fine when I use bluebird promises:

```
import * as Promise from 'bluebird';

getAccount(id) {
    var account = find(accounts, ['id', id]);
    return account ?
        Promise.resolve(account) :
        Promise.reject(new NotFoundError());
}
```

`NotFoundError` is defined as follows:

```
export function NotFoundError(message = 'Not Found') {
    this.name = 'NotFoundError';
    this.message = message;
    this.stack = (new Error()).stack;
}
NotFoundError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
NotFoundError.prototype.constructor = NotFoundError;
```

However, if I remove the import of bluebird in `getAccount()` and let node.js take over promises, the code fails inside the `NotFoundError()` constructor because `this` is not defined. Specifically, the constructor is called twice, once correctly from the `getAccount()` code shown above and a second time by node.js's `_tickCallback()` function with `this` as undefined:

```
NotFoundError (errors.js:13)
runMicrotasksCallback (internal/proces…ext_tick.js:58)
_combinedTickCallback (internal/proces…ext_tick.js:67)
_tickCallback (internal/proces…ext_tick.js:98)
```

Why is node.js calling the `NotFoundError()` constructor a second time and that too incorrectly!!!

Please help.

Comment: I can't reproduce with Node v8 using the code that you're posting.

Comment: I am on node v6.9.5. I can try with v8, but we have not moved to that version yet.

Comment: I also can't reproduce with Node v6. Can you create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Yep time to create MCVE.

Comment: @robertklep, while I create a MCVE, here's the example that I am working on: https://github.com/archfirst/node-es6-rest-template. README.md shows how to run the tests. The last test reproduces the problem when I take out the import of bluebird.

Comment: import works in node? in my node8 can't use import * as Promise from 'bluebird';.. why ?

Comment: I am on node6 which does not support imports. I am using babel to transpile this down to ES5. I suspect node8 has the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused [by this line](https://github.com/archfirst/node-es6-rest-template/blob/a7122bcf523bfd7b8b3d51478259f61fd7ec7eae/src/adapters/account.adapter.js#L56):

```
.catch(NotFoundError, function() { ... })
```

Native promises don't have an option to pass a specific error class to a `catch` method, so what happens is that when an error occurs, `NotFoundError` is called (without a `new` in front of it) because it's presumed to be the catch handler.

Comment: Wow! Didn't know that. Is there an alternate way to do this?

Comment: The only way is to have a single `catch` handler and check the type of the error to determine what action to take.

Comment: Thanks so much, @roberklep. You rock!